# How do I change my audio output device without making it the default one?

Tags: windows-7

I want to combine two streams using a program called Virtual Audio Cable, and listen to the combined stream, while not making it the DEFAULT sound output device.

Is there a way to listen to an output WITHOUT making it the default one?

Answer (score 2):

I recently found a small application that works perfectly and it's way better than the `AutoHotKey` which you have to compile on your own: [SoundSwitch](http://soundswitch.codeplex.com)

Comment: This is much better than the (potentially error-prone) AutoHotKey approach. Also, you don't have to compile it on your own - it's just a tray application to install. Works perfectly for me!

Comment: I upvoted you but I lack the power to accept your answer, since I'm not the original questioner. Sorry!

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't pay attention

Answer (score 1):

Well, a little technical info could help, but...

If you go to control panel-> sounds->hardware, click on the device you want to access, and select properties, and disable it (it *will* disable it, but all references to it as"default" should remain)

Hope that helped